# Impossible to show errors with PHP under IIS7.5

Tags: php, iis, iis-7

The server is : Win 2008 R2
Php version is 5.2 if I remember correctly. (has been installed along with wordpress & mysql with WPI).

I did install wordpress along with arras-theme. On some pages I do have 500 errors. Problem is, can't really debug and fix the error as it's 500, no errors are showing (no fatal/warning/notice or nothing).

In the php.ini error section I have those settings :

```
error_reporting = E_ALL  
display_errors = Off  
display_startup_errors = Off  
log_errors =On  
log_errors_max_len = 1024  
ignore_repeated_errors = Off  
ignore_repeated_source = Off  
report_memleaks = On  
track_errors = Off  
error_log = "C:\\inetpub\\logs\\php_error_log.txt"
```

The log file is write+read on Users, Administrators and Network Service.

I tried to update the machine.config with Detailed errors instead of DetailedLocalOnly but it didin't really helped as I still got a standard 500 error page.

There is nothing in the event viewer (editing php.ini with syslog does nothing).

Weird enough, it seems that for some errors I get a blank page.

I tried to make a test page with only this : `<?php echo 1/0; ?>` but it showd only a blank page instead of the expected fatal error.

In the trace I made I got only this informations :

```
No.175. Warning -MODULE_SET_RESPONSE_ERROR_STATUS 

ModuleName FastCgiModule
Notification 128
HttpStatus 500
HttpReason Internal Server Error
HttpSubStatus 0
ErrorCode 0
ConfigExceptionInfo
Notification EXECUTE_REQUEST_HANDLER
ErrorCode The operation completed successfully. (0x0)
```

I tried to read IIS' forums as much as I could and do some tryouts but I seems to be able to do nothing but hit a wall so far.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Read http://blogs.iis.net/kehand/archive/2009/08/09/php-and-custom-error-pages.aspx for workaround to this issue. This will be fixed in Win2K8 R2 SP1 so that errors returned by FastCGI processes won't be overridden by IIS custom error module.

Thanks,
Kanwal

Comment: nice one ... tho I only get a white page for some errors. It's weird I will have to investigate into this.

Comment: And weirdly enough, I still can't seem to write to the PHP log. But it gives me some good insight on where to search, thanks !

Comment: Doesn't seem to be fixed in Wind2008 R2 SP1. And workaround doesn't solve it either.